# Is there a LL(1) grammar for the language with equal number of a's and b's?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, parsers

Consider the following CFG.

$S \rightarrow \epsilon\ |\ aSbS\ |\ bSaS$

Can we prove formally that an equivalent $LL(1)$ grammar does not exist? I feel that intuitively an equivalent $LL(1)$ grammar doesn't exist, but I'm unable to prove this formally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language for the grammar in the question is the set of all words with equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s.

I am afraid your intuition is incorrect. Here is an $LL(1)$ grammar for the language.

$\qquad S \to AS \mid BS \mid \epsilon$
$\qquad A \to aXb$
$\qquad X \to AX \mid \epsilon$
$\qquad B \to bYa$
$\qquad Y \to BY \mid\epsilon$

Here is some statistics about the grammar above .
$$\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{nonterminal}  &\text{first set}   &\text{follow set}  &\text{nullable}    &\text{endable}\\\hline
S   &a\ b   &\emptyset  &\text{yes} &\text{yes}\\\hline
A   &a      &a\ \ b     &\text{no}  &\text{yes}\\\hline
X   &a      &b          &\text{yes} &\text{no} \\\hline
B   &b      &b\ \ a     &\text{no}  &\text{yes}\\\hline
Y   &b      &a          &\text{yes} &\text{no} \\\hline
\end{array}$$

Here is the parsing table.
$$\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}\hline
    &a  &b  &{\\\$}   \\\hline
S  &S\to AS  &S\to BS   &S\to \epsilon\\\hline
A  &A\to aXb & & \\\hline
X  &X\to AX  &X\to\epsilon & \\\hline
B  &         &B\to bYa  &\\\hline
Y  &Y\to\epsilon &Y\to BY  & \\\hline
\end{array}$$

**Exercise 1.** Show that both the grammar in the question and the grammar above generate the language of words with equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s.

**Exercise 2.** Consider the following grammar.
$\qquad S \to AS \mid BS \mid \epsilon$
$\qquad A \to aU$
$\qquad U \to AbA \mid b$
$\qquad B \to bV$
$\qquad V \to BaB \mid a$
Show that the grammar above also generate the language of words with equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s. Show that it is $LL(1)$.

**Exercise 3.** The following grammar also generate the language of equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s. Explain why it is not $LL(1)$.
$\qquad S \to AS \mid BS \mid \epsilon$
$\qquad A \to aAbA \mid \epsilon$
$\qquad B \to bBaB \mid \epsilon$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I realize my intuition was wrong.

Comment: It seems that your grammar *cannot* generate the sentence `aababb` which contains equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s.

Comment: @hengxin Thanks! I just fixed the critical error.